# Can you feel a feeling you don't know about? Could it affect your emotions?

Tags: logic, ethics, epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

So, do you believe someone can feel lonely if they don't know what loneliness is?

Don't you think people don't like / like loneliness based on experience (someone who never gets to be alone usually somewhat likes being alone and vice versa)? 
Does that mean that if there was a world with absolutely no privacy and being alone was rare, loneliness would be correlated to a pleasant feeling or emotion?

Could this be a possible way to leverage ignorance to ones own benefit?

Comment: There are too many questions here. But one or two might be answered by familiarity with [alexithymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia), or "a [personality trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_trait) characterized by the [subclinical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subclinical) inability to identify and describe emotions experienced by oneself.[[1](https://doi.org/10.1159%2F000286529)][[2](https://doi.org/10.1016%2F0022-3999%2894%2990005-1)][[3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0191886917304956)]".

Answer (score 2):

Just because you don't know what gravity is doesn't mean you can't experience it. So yes, people can definitely feel a feeling even if they haven't conceptualized it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine feeling something you have not experienced. For example, a person who has never been alone might read a book about someone being alone and imagine what it feels like. He might get some inclination about what it feels like, but without physically experiencing it, it would only be a guess. How you feel in a situation also depends on your history. For example, if you mentally prepared yourself to be alone for a day, it might not feel that bad. Feelings are ultimately in our head, but I would argue that an actual experience is fundamentally different from our imagination.